# Permission denied to edit batch & autoit(au3) file using ruby script

Tags: ruby, batch-processing, autoit, batch-rename

My directory contains bat & autoit file

My ruby script

```
Dir.foreach('C:/Users/Public/qa/Libs/Model') do |file|

  puts file
  aFile=File.open("C:/Users/Public/qa/Libs/Model/#{file}","r")
    IO.foreach(aFile){|block| aFile.puts block.gsub(/Model_No/,"#{Model_No}")}
        aFile.close
  end
```

Error generated

```
C:/Users/Public/qa/Testcases/Default_test/temp.rb:23:in `initialize': Permission denied - C:/Users/Public/qa/Libs/Model/. (Errno::EACCES)
    from C:/Users/Public/qa/Testcases/Default_test/temp.rb:23:in `open'
    from C:/Users/Public/qa/Testcases/Default_test/temp.rb:23:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Users/Public/qa/Testcases/Default_test/temp.rb:20:in `foreach'
    from C:/Users/Public/qa/Testcases/Default_test/temp.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Error was because of "." and ".."

```
Dir.foreach('C:/Users/Public/qa/Libs/Model_No') do |fil|


  if !File.directory?(fil)
    puts fil


  aFile=File.open("C:/Users/Public/qa/Libs/Model_No/#{fil}","r+")
    IO.foreach(aFile){|block| aFile.puts block.gsub(/123/,"#{Model_No}")}
        aFile.close
    end
end
```